# i need convert SQL query to Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: symfony, symfony4, query-builder, dql

**I have a relation ManyToMany and the tables in my databases are :**

- article              :  (id,titre,description,category,createAt)
- article_groupe_auteur:  (article_id,groupe_auteur_id)
- groupe_auteur        :  (id,nom,prenom,adress,institution,city)

**i need to to retrive the authors relied to an article.**

### Sql Query

```
use RevueProject;
 select nom_auteur,prenom_auteur,nom_ins,adresse_ins from groupe_auteur ga
     INNER JOIN
                article_groupe_auteur aga on groupe_auteur.id = aga.groupe_auteur_id
     INNER JOIN article a on aga.article_id = a.id
                where  a.id=21;
```

### Dql Query

```
 public function SelectArticleAuthors2(int $Id){

  return $this->createQueryBuilder('GA');
              ->innerJoin('article_groupe_auteur','aga', Join::WITH , 'aga = ga.groupe_auteur_id')
              ->innerJoin('article','a',Join::WITH , 'a = aga.article_id')
              ->where('aga.article_id = : Id')
              ->setParameter('Id', $Id);
              ->getQuery()->getResult()
}
```

Comment: do your **entities** actually have **properties** named `groupe_auteur_id`? or do you have them properly set up as one/many-to-many/one relations? looks weird to me. usually you can join via `innerJoin('GA.articles', 'a')` or similar, because the condition would then be implied by the defined relation.

Comment: hey Jukumi i dont have groupe_auteur_id in my entities its just property in new table created by the relation  ManyToMany  i tried ; innerJoin('GA.articles', 'a') but i dont know what i missed

Comment: well you probably should have an error message maybe? or is it just happily returning empty results?

Comment: yes it gives a error : Semantical Error] line 0, col 53 near 'article_groupe_auteur': Error: Class 'article_groupe_auteur' is not defined.

Comment: the query builder works with entities and their properties/relations. So you can join in `innerJoin(ArticleGroupAuteur::class, ...)` (if your entity is called that way), but I find it easier to use the form I've mentioned before. errors are not all the same, so you should calmly handle them one by one.

Comment: thank you so much Jukumi i fixed the problem i will post the solution here to help other in cas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Its how i get the authors relied to an specify article by a relation ManyToMany

```
class GroupeAuteurRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function SelectArticleAuthors(int $id)
    {
        // ga (alias) : GroupeAuteur Entity 
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('ga') 
                    // articles (collection)
                    ->innerJoin('ga.articles','a','WITH','a.id=:id') 
                    ->setParameter('id', $id)
                    ->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: the with looks really weird, I would have put it in a where. but technically it's the same, so ... whatever ;o)

Comment: yes its ,you are right but it works fine if you have any suggestion let me know to try it :)